# Tratar request redirecionado pelo Htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, rotas

Estou estudando sobre roteamento, tentando (re)criar uma solução de routing minha.

Sempre usei o seguinte `.htaccess` pra redirecionar meus requests:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Aí era fácil, era só pegar o `$_GET['url']` no `index.php` e tratar como eu bem quisesse.
Mas venho me deparando com o seguinte `.htacesss`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Minha duvida é como pegar o que foi passado, já que ele não joga o request no `$_GET['url']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira a qual você poderia fazer isso é da seguinte forma, onde o .htaccess ficaria assim:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

E o script php ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uriParts = explode('/', $uri);

var_dump($uriParts);
```

Então assim supondo que você acessasse a seguinte url por exemplo:

http://localhost/seu_projeto/segmento_1/segmento_2/segmento_3

Resultaria no seguinte output:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string 'seu_projeto' (length=11)
  2 => string 'segmento_1' (length=10)
  3 => string 'segmento_2' (length=10)
  4 => string 'segmento_3' (length=10)
```

Assim dessa forma usando o array $uriParts, você pode vir a tratar as requisições feitas em sua aplicação.

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado. Sanou minha dúvida :D